# Design pattern for a report with input data and configuration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I need to present a user profile publicly, in which user can choose what to show and what not to show. My design is:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_data
  belongs_to :report_config
  delegate :show_name, :show_address, :to => :report_config
  delegate :name, :address, :to => :user_data
  def filter_data
    report = self.user_data
    report.name = nil if show_name.false?
    report.address = nil if show_address.false?
    return report
  end
end


class UserData  < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :report
end

class ReportConfig  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :report
end
```

However, this is not a very good design, because calling `filter_data` on a Report object would return a child object. How can I allow `Report` to have all attributes from child objects?

I am thinking of inheritance (i.e., Report inherits UserData and ReportConfig, but it won't work). What are other design patterns that could fit into my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate all attributes of User model what you want with meta programming in ruby.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_data
  belongs_to :report_config
  delegate :show_name, :show_address, :to => :report_config

  self.class_eval do
    #reject the attributes what you don't want to delegate
    UserData.new.attribute_names.reject { |n| %w(id created_at updated_at).include?(n) }.each do |n|
      delegate n , to: :user_data
    end
  end

  def filter_data    
    name = nil if show_name.false?
    address = nil if show_address.false?    
  end
end
```

When you use it, you just initialize a Report:

```
report = Report.find_by_user_data_id(YOUR USER DATA ID)
report.filter_data

report.name
report.address
report.....
```

On the other hand, Do you really need a report object? What about just using your UserData and ReportConfig?

```
class UserData  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report_config
  delegate :show_name, :show_address, :to => :report_config

  def report_name
    name if show_name
  end

  def report_address
    address if show_address
  end      
end

class ReportConfig  < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I don't know the detailed requirement and just try to supply an option. Hope it helps :)